# Install4j: can installation executable be removed after install?

Tags: install4j

My Install4j configuration has no problem updating my executable and replacing the old instance.

However, my windows user profile is building up with each instance of the downloaded executable file:

- install_1.0.0.exe
- install_1.0.1.exe
- install_1.0.2.exe

If I update to version 1.0.3, then I will see install_exe_1.0.3.exe stored here as well.

Is it possible for Install4j to delete this file upon update completion?

FWIW, this also occurs with Install4j updates.  I have the following files in my user profile:

- install4j_windows_5_1_10_with_jre.exe
- install4j_windows_5_1_11_with_jre.exe
- install4j_windows_5_1_12_with_jre.exe
- install4j_windows_5_1_13_with_jre.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 5.x, there is no clean-up mechanism for downloaded update installers, but you could build one yourself.

The place to add logic for deleting old installers would be in the updater. Each time a new installer is downloaded, you would have to save the download path to a persistent storage, such as the Java preferences store. When the updater is started, you could then load those saved paths and delete them.